# Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

my problem is that i have to mail crystal reports through outlook to different vendors. I've got the solution how to mail through outlook but the problem that i am facing now is that i have to attach the report and the report should be such that it shows details of a particular row from the database. i tried using .rpt file and attached it but since .rpt is a saved data the same data goes to all the vendors and not a different quotation.

Answer (score 2):

The "rpt" file itself is just the definition of the report. It doesn't contain data. You'll have to run the report and export it in some file format, e.g. as PDF. You could attach that PDF file to your email.

Answer (score 0):

Like splattne said...You would use a report parameter for the vendor. Set the parameter value before calling [ReportDocument.ExportToDisk()](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXI/en/en/CrystalReports_dotNET_SDK/crystalreports_net_doc/doc/crsdk_net_doc/html/crlrfreportdocumentclassexporttodiskmethodtopic.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There are different options to do what you want. The most popular one is bursting. You will create a report wich returns information for all vendors and  group data by vendor. Then use a software to parse and save this report to separate files per vendor, which will be emailed to the vendors' email address ( part of the report too).

If you have BOE you can use bursting publication, otherwise you can check this website for 3rd party solutions , which support bursting: http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/desktop-scheduling-engines

Most of the solutions are paid, but there are generally affordable. There are some free options like this one:

http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx